# Is there a way to measure how much time takes to import a file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, jestjs, babeljs

Let's say I have a file that imports 2 other files and one of those files imports a bunch of others.

Is there a way to measure how much time it takes from a compilation (babel) perspective?

Some background:
I'm working on a "big" project and jest (+ babel-jest) tests started to be very slow, like for example, a simple test is taking 40 seconds when actual tests take just 45 ms. I've measured that with:

```js
...
beforeAll(() => {
  console.time('RUN');
});
afterAll(() => {
  console.timeEnd('RUN');
});
...
```

Getting:

```
RUN 45ms
```

So I'm assuming those almost 40 seconds are just compilation and stuff.

Digging it down a little bit found that a dependency of the file being tested has a lot of dependencies (like just importing it results in more than 800 files imported). Making that dependency to avoid importing any other file, makes the test to run in 3 seconds.

I'm looking for a tool or some code to measure how much time takes to import a file when compiling.

Comment: have you tried to run `jest --maxWorkers=4`? I know it is unrelated but that actually speed up our test quite a bit

Comment: Yes, thanks. But what I’m looking is to identify what is slowing down my tests

Comment: Babel compilation will happen *before* your tests are executed. So that doesn't explain the delta.

Comment: `But what I’m looking is to identify what is slowing down my tests` -- You're looking for a *profiler.*

Comment: In fact, Chrome Developer tools already has one; see [here](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/javascript-profiling-chrome-developer-tools/).

Comment: @fjc That's what I'm guessing, the issue isn't the test itself or the execution but all the time it takes to compile or setup the test

Comment: Googling finds https://github.com/toomuchdesign/babel-timing

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes, I tried that. I see a some `requireModuleOrMock` taking 40 seconds and below it a bunch of `requireModuleOrMock` with several `transform`, `traverse`, `visit`, etc. all babel functions. In summary I think it is showing me that it is taking a lot to compile as I was guessing, right?

Comment: @meriton I found that and tried it but I got a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined` within an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` when running it. Tried to find some solutions in the repo and googling with no results.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Some results: https://imgur.com/gallery/sWsrIBB https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s3bzOAkHJsrXebOIfkbouE6xAKApDk02/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for: https://imgur.com/a/5dFvB15 :) Thanks, @RobertHarvey

Comment: @meriton Finally I was able to make it work using the jest integration. It's really nice but it shows the total time it takes to parse a file. It is a good metric but it doesn't show a total time of it and its imports, so basically I was looking for a tool to find "culprits" and it doesn't allow me to find them completely. Thanks!

Comment: @inakiabt Did you end up finding culprit and speeding up test prep times? I am facing the same problem

Comment: @libby I ended extending the babel-timing package to generate a big tree (using a js tree library + some HTML and CSS) of dependencies and its build times. The implementation was very ugly and custom to be published :) 
But it helped me in some way to reduce the dependencies and make the tests a little bit faster.